# Google Plus Login API not working on production server

Tags: api, authentication, google-plus

I have implemented the google plus api on development server and it works fine. I used the same code on production server. But after requesting the permission it takes a long time to return to my site and login.

Can anyone please let me know what might be the cause. I have used oauth2.

Below is the code I am using

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'googleplus/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'googleplus/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';

class Webpage_UserGPlusLogin extends Webpage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $temp_redirect = $_SESSION['RETURN_URL_AFTERLOGIN'];
        $this->title = 'User Account';

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName(WEBSITE_NAME); 
        $client->setClientId(GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_ID); // Client Id
        $client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_PLUS_CLIENT_SECRET); // Client Secret
        $client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_PLUS_REDIRECT_URI); // Redirect Uri set while creating API account
        $client->setDeveloperKey(GOOGLE_PLUS_DEVELOPER_KEY); // Developer Key
        $oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);


        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            $redirect = GOOGLE_PLUS_REDIRECT_URI;
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); // Redirects to same page
            return;
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        }

        if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
            $client->revokeToken();
        }

        if(!isset($_SESSION['email_address_user_account'])) // Check if user is already logged in or not
        {
            if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
                $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();  // Google API call to get current user information

                $email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                $img = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
                $googleuserid = $user['id'];
                $given_name = $user['given_name'];
                $family_name = $user['family_name'];
                // The access token may have been updated lazily.
                $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

                // If email address is present in DB return user data else insert user info in DB
                $this->result = UserAccount::gplus_sign_up($email, $googleuserid, $given_name, $family_name); 

                // Create new user object.
                $this->user_account = new UserAccount($this->result['id'],$this->result['email_address'],$this->result['password'],$this->result['confirmation_code'],$this->result['is_confirmed'], $this->result['first_name'], $this->result['last_name']); 

                $_SESSION['gplus_email_address'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['gplus_first_name'] = $given_name;
                $_SESSION['gplus_last_name'] = $family_name;
                $_SESSION['gplus_id'] = $googleuserid;
                $_SESSION['gplus_profile_pic'] = $img;
                $_SESSION['email_address_user_account'] = $email;

            } else {
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            }
        }

        if(isset($temp_redirect))
            header("Location:".$temp_redirect);
        else
            header("Location:/");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is anything appearing in the JavaScript console of your browser when you try to connect using the production site?

You also indicate you're using the same code, are you also using the same registration in the API console?

Finally, you're saying it takes a long time to return - does the rest of the authentication flow actually work after this? Or are you seeing other problems?

Comment: This is very vague, can you post your code that you're initiating the flow with to help us diagnose the problem? Also, if you're able to post a link to the site that the problem is occurring that might help too.

Comment: @Prisoner I tried using same API console as well as different one but no success:(, Yes the authentication flow works but it takes a long time say 2-3 Mins.

Comment: Can you post your front-end code too? Need to see how you are initiating the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

use following code

```
$temp = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
$request = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json";                
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$request);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization: OAuth '.$temp->access_token));
$response = trim(curl_exec($curl));
$info =  curl_getinfo($curl);
$request_header_info = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);

//var_dump($info);
//var_dump($request_header_info);           
curl_close($curl);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($response));
```

instade of

```
$user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();  // Google API call to get current user information`enter code here`
```

Hope this will help you .. :)